submanifold of constant curvature
If we have $N↪(M,h)$ wih $N$ totally umbilic submanifold and $M$ of constant curvature, I want to prove that $N$ is of constant curvature too.
Attempt
Using Gauss equation, we have:
$R^M(X,Y,Z,W)=R^N(X,Y,Z,W)+h(\mathbf{II}(X,Z),\mathbf{II}(Y,W))-h(\mathbf{II}(X,W),\mathbf{II}(Y,Z))$
Also, $M$ being of constant curvature $k$, we have that:
$$R^M(X,Y,Z,W)=k(h(X,W)h(Y,Z)-h(X,Z)h(Y,W))$$
$N$ is totally umbilic means that the shape operator $S_{\eta}$ is proportional to the identity, where $\eta\in\Gamma(TN^{\perp})$ is a smooth normal vector field along $N$. I have tried using these formulas
$S_{\eta}(X)=-(\nabla^M_X\eta)^T$ and $h(S_{\eta}(X),Y)=h(\mathbf{II}(X,Y),\eta)$, but I don't really reach a conclusion.
